# InvalidRequestException while iot.registerThing using thing template even though validate-template is success

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am trying to provision thing using provisioning template. I validated the template using aws cloudformation validate-template cli, it was validated successfully. When I use that template to register a thing I am getting InvalidRequestException: Invalid registration template. Template format error: unsupported type or structure exception.

I have validated the template using the following CLI: -
aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://test/test.template

```
config.templateBody = `{
  "Parameters" : {
      "ThingName" : {
          "Type" : "String"
      },
      "SerialNumber" : {
          "Type" : "String"
      },
      "Landscape" : {
          "Type" : "String",
          "Default" : "WA"
      },
      "CertificateId" : {
          "Type" : "String"    
      }
  },
  "Resources" : {
      "thing" : {
          "Type" : "AWS::IoT::Thing",
          "Properties" : {
              "ThingName" : {"Ref" : "ThingName"},
              "AttributePayload" : { "version" : "v1", "serialNumber" :  {"Ref" : "SerialNumber"}, "Landscape" : {"Ref" : "Landscape"}}, 
              "ThingTypeName" :  "EC"
          }
      },
      "certificate" : {
          "Type" : "AWS::IoT::Certificate",
          "Properties" : {
              "CertificateId": {"Ref" : "CertificateId"}
          }
      },
      "policy" : {
          "Type" : "AWS::IoT::Policy",
          "Properties" : {
              "PolicyDocument" : "{ \"Version\": \"2012-10-17\", \"Statement\": [{ \"Effect\": \"Allow\", \"Action\":[\"iot:Publish\"], \"Resource\": \"*\" }] }"
          }
      }
  }   
}`

var params = {
                templateBody:config.templateBody,
                parameters:{
                    ThingName: serialNumber,
                    SerialNumber: serialNumber,
                    Landscape: landscape,
                    CertificateId: '<id>'
                },
            }

    const iot = new AWS.Iot();
    iot.registerThing(params, function(err, data){
                if (err) {
                    console.log("[applycert] Error while registering thing:" + err.stack);
                    callback(null, err);
                }
```

I expected that the register thing should register successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It is a JSON formatting issue. Somehow AWS does not like the string I'd given. Resolved by using

```
config.templateBody = JSON.stringify({
  Parameters : {
      ThingName : {
          Type : String
      },
      SerialNumber : {
          Type : String
      },
      Landscape : {
          Type : String,
          Default : "dev"
      },
      CSR : {
        Type : "String"    
      }
  }....})
```